# When the this value of .call() & .apply() can be `null` or `undefined`?

Tags: javascript

When the `this` value of `Function.prototype.call()` & `Function.prototype.apply()`  can be `null` or `undefined`?

Take the example of the code below:

```
var numbers = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];
var min = Math.min.apply(null, numbers);
```

Example from [MDN Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Edit:
The original question has a third part and a different example:

> When the `this` value of .call() & .apply() can be `null` or `undefined` or even none?
>
> Take the example of
>
> Array.prototype.slice.call(auguements);

*I thought there has no this value,but thanks to @guest271314 now I know that was stupid*

Comment: `arguments` is the `this` for `.slice()`

Comment: Oh,I see,that was stupid.@guest271314

Comment: Why did you remove the example from Question?

Comment: Well, yes, if you use `Function.prototype.call()` then the `this` value inside `Function.prototype` is `undefined`. I don't get what you are asking for (or asking about).

Comment: @guest271314 Cause it's irrelevant

Comment: It's not irrelevant: now the question makes no sense. It can be `null` or `undefined` when it can be.

Comment: @zerkms I'll change it

Comment: _"I'll change it"_ The updated Question does not have the same `javascript` or description as `js` example and description which appeared at  original Question?

Comment: @guest271314 But this is what I want to ask,code is form [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: _"But this is what I want to ask"_ Certainly. It is your Question. Only noting that the original Question and present Question appear to be different.

Comment: @HaoZonggang, generally speaking, in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) can you pass `null` or `undefined` as the scope. To your current example: here `null` is passed as the `this` of `Math.min()`, because it's primarily about passing an Array of arguments to the function. And 2nd Math.min is a utility-function and doesn't care about the passed `this`. So **this particular `null`** means as much as `I don't give a f* I just want to pass the second argument to apply()`

Comment: @Thomas—please do not refer to a function's *this* as "scope", they are entirely different concepts.

Comment: @guest271314 Fine I'll add it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be `null` or `undefined` only in strict mode.

In sloppy mode they will be ignored, and you will get the global object instead.

```js
function logThis() {
  console.log(this === window); // true :(
}
logThis.call(undefined);
logThis.call(null);
logThis.apply(undefined);
logThis.apply(null);
```

This is defined in [OrdinaryCallBindThis](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis), used by [[[Call]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist)

> 5. If *thisMode* is strict, let *thisValue* be *thisArgument*.
> 6. Else
>
>    1. if *thisArgument* is **null** or **undefined**, then
>
>       1. Let *thisValue* be *calleeRealm*.[[globalThis]].
>    2. Else
>
>       1. Let *thisValue* be [ToObject](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toobject)(*thisArgument*).

If you want to know if calling a function with a `null` or `undefined` `this` value will break it, then you need to know what that function will attempt to do with the `this` value.

In your example, `Math.min` completely ignores the `this` value, so it doesn't matter what value you pass. However, since it's a `Math` method, it might make sense to pass `Math` instead of `null` or `undefined`.

```
Math.min.apply(Math, [5, 6, 2, 3, 7]); // 2
```

Comment: I guess I'd better read some more documents rather than looking for quick answers here

Comment: @HaoZonggang—also, *this* **can** be null or undefined anytime you like in strict mode, however it might be better to ask when it is appropriate to do that (which would be any time you don't care what the called function's *this* value is). Sometimes *null* is used to indicate that, even in non–strict mode where it will resolve to the global object.

Comment: @oriol Now I know why this happens `str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, rotCharArray);`

Comment: @HaoZonggang Also consider the ES6 spread operator, `Math.min(...[5, 6, 2, 3, 7])` and `String.fromCharCode(...rotCharArray)`